# RailsのActiveRecord::Relationのeachについて

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

```
u = User.find(1)
u.class #=> User
u.class == User #=> true
```

---

```
uw = User.where(id: 1)
uw.class == ActiveRecord::Relation #=> false
uw.class < ActiveRecord::Relation #=> true

uw.class #=> User::ActiveRecord_Relation
uw.all.class #=> User::ActiveRecord_Relation

uw.each{|o| puts o.class #=> User }
```

---

`uw.all.class`ですが**Array**を返すと思っていたのですが、
**ActiveRecord::Relation**を継承した**User::ActiveRecord_Relation**でした。

さて、`uw.each`の`each`ですが、これはどのオブジェクトのメソッドでしょうか？
[ActiveRecord::Relation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html)
ドキュメントには見当たらないように思います。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

手元のRailsプロジェクトで調べてみるとこのように表示されました。

```
irb(main):009:0> Student.all.method(:each).source_location
=> ["/Users/jit/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb", 46]
```

GitHub上ではこちらのコードになります。

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v4.2.4/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb#L46

メソッドの定義場所がわからない場合は、`source_location`メソッドを使うと便利です。

参考： [Rubyでメソッドの定義場所を見つける方法 - Qiita](http://qiita.com/jnchito/items/fc8a61b421d026a23ffe)